# По аккаунту Apple Developer подскажите

Tags: apple, account

Подскажите, аккаунт Apple Developer для публикации в TestFlight и AppStore кому должен принадлежать? Заказчику или Разработчику?
Само приложение принадлежит Заказчику.

Comment: Нефига у эпл там всё строга. Помню из интернета скачал готовый проект, изменил название и спокойно залили в гугл плей)

Comment: Ну да строго. У меня вопрос же не как обойти Apple, а на кого лучше зарегать аккаунт разработчика.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Логично, что аккаунт должен принадлежать заказчику.

Разработчик, по факту, лишь его сотрудник и к правообладанию приложением он никак не относится.

Comment: Вот и я так думаю)